# How to know which controller/action user was redirected from?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Being inside controller action or view, is there any way to know which controller/action user has been just redirected from? There is Request.UrlReferrer, but it's Url, I need to know Controller and/or action names instead.

Answer (score 0):

> There is Request.UrlReferrer, but it's Url, I need to know Controller and/or action names instead.

Given an Url as string you could parse it and obtain the corresponding controller and action names using the following approach:

```
var url = new Uri("http://example.com/somecontroller/someaction?foo=bar");

var request = new HttpRequest(null, url.AbsoluteUri, url.Query);
var response = new HttpResponse(StringWriter.Null);
var httpContext = new HttpContext(request, response);

var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));

string controllerName = (string)routeData.Values["controller"];
string actionName = (string)routeData.Values["action"];
```

Obviously at the place where I used `http://example.com/somecontroller/someaction?foo=bar` you could use `Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri`.

Needless to say that this approach is absolutely unreliable. A much better solution is to simply pass the required information as parameters to the controller action from the calling action.